# SQL Query with records starts with and contain with

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**QUESTION:** *I need to develop a query that looks for certain records that starts with a search term and records that contains the search term. Furthermore, both subsets should be sorted by a certain column, whereas the resultant set shouldn't be sorted. Records starting with term should come above the contains term records.*

Example: I have `students` table and I want all students whose names start with "Jhon". Students having the first name "Jhon" should come first and after then all those students whose last name is "Jhon".

What I have are as following:

- Got all records starting with the search term and save it into a temptable_A , than got all records all records containing the search term and excluding results that are already in temptable_A and save into temptable_B. Now both temptable should have respected results, so I dump tempTable_B into tempTable_A, believing that the new records are append at last of the table. But they are not, they are inserted in and are sorted, where are I haven't applied sorting.
- I have done the same with a merge statement and it does the same thing, but no fruitful result.
- I have tried Union between both sub queries (Start with and contains) but the resultant dataset always doesn't show the start with records on top.

Scenario:
Students Table with column
Id | Student

`select *  FROM students where name like 'jhon%'`

`UNION`

`select * FROM students where name like '%jhon%'`

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please show what code you have currently, with sample input, current output, and desired output, and explain what you are asking readers about the same.

Comment: Remember that records in tables are not ordered - you must always specify order while querying data. You should add new column into temp table, `group_order` or something. Set it 1 for first batch, 2 for second batch and sort/query final results by `order by group_order, certain_column`.

Comment: Your "Question" isn't a question, you don't ask anything. You tell us what you "need", but don't give us anything to answer. What are you asking here?

Comment: Why use a `UNION` and 2 parses of the table `students` and not a simple `OR`?

Comment: @Larnu
The need is the problem statement.
with OR I will not be able to sort records with respect to "Starts With Records" and then "Contains Records"

Comment: @Larnu order by will work fine for records that starts with the term, but when start with and contains dataset is merged, I want the start with records to show above the contains record.

Comment: *Why*? What's wrong with `ORDER BY CASE WHEN [name] LIKE 'jhon%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `order by`.  For instance:

```
select s.*
from students
where name like '%jhon%'
order by charindex('jhon', name);
```

This orders by how far down `'jhon'` is in the string.  If you just want the ones that start `'jhon'` first, you can use a `case` expression:

```
order by (case when name like 'jhon%' then 1 else 2 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a case expression in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select * from students where Name like '%jhon%'    -- select all students containing john
order by
    case                                           -- order by place of match first
        when Name like 'john%' then 0
        when Name like '%john%' then 1
    end,
    Name                                           -- then order by Name
```